# Testing for exceptions in async methods

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit, fluent-assertions

I'm a bit stuck with this code (this is a sample):

```
public async Task Fail()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception(); });
}

[Test]
public async Task TestFail()
{
    Action a = async () => { await Fail(); };
    a.ShouldThrow<Exception>();
}
```

The code doesn't catch the exception, and fails with

> Expected a System.Exception to be thrown, but no exception was
>   thrown.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but docs seem to suggest this is the way to go. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Missed. Doesn't fix the issue, though.

Comment: what is the **issue**?

Comment: @stuartd Actually, no, async is req'd when testing async methods. ShouldThrow is not async. Could that be a reason?

Comment: @user227895 this works for me: `Assert.CatchAsync<Exception>(async () => await Fail());`

Comment: Your problem is `Action` - this creates an `async void` method. The proper asynchronous delegate equivalent is `Func<Task>`.

Comment: There's no reason for `Fail` to call `Task.Run`, it can just throw an exception, and there's no reason for `TestFail` to have an anonymous method, you can just use `Fail` for the delegate without wrapping it in another method call that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You should use `Func<Task>` instead of `Action`:

```
[Test]
public void TestFail()
{
    Func<Task> f = async () => { await Fail(); };
    f.ShouldThrow<Exception>();            
}
```

That will call the following extension which is used to verify asynchronous methods

```
public static ExceptionAssertions<TException> ShouldThrow<TException>(
    this Func<Task> asyncAction, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
        where TException : Exception
```

Internally this method will run task returned by `Func` and wait for it. Something like

```
try
{
    Task.Run(asyncAction).Wait();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // get actual exception if it wrapped in AggregateException
}
```

Note that test itself is synchronous.

Comment: Is the async await really necessary? Seems to work fine with just `Func<Task> f = () => Fail();`

Comment: It is if you are interested in waiting for the call to finish execution before the test does.

Comment: FYI - in the latest version (v5) of fluentassertions the syntax is: f.Should().Throw<Exception>

Comment: If the `ShouldThrow` method awaits the resultant task it shouldnt matter if you await it in the func should it?

Comment: Don't know if it's new or it was available back then already, but [official website](https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/) says that action can by used as well. Even though I couldn't make it work for some reason.

Answer (score 47):

With Fluent Assertions v5+ the code will be like :

```
ISubject sut = BuildSut();
//Act and Assert
Func<Task> sutMethod = async () => { await sut.SutMethod("whatEverArgument"); };
await sutMethod.Should().ThrowAsync<Exception>();
```

This should work.

Comment: Is there not an await missing? `await sutMethod.Should().ThrowAsync<Exception>();`

Comment: I think in the 3rd row, the async-await keyword-pair is unnecessary, it works for me without it as well.

Comment: @Károly Ozsvárt : I think it works for you since the code you are testing does not have a an await that requires continuation before hitting the expected throw. This will be common for validation code in a method (since it s usual first) and might be common in a test since all dependencies are probably mocked to return completed tasks. But, it won't work if you hit a continuation.

Comment: The synchronous version `sutMethod.Should().Throw<Exception>();` worked for me as well. I think this is just blocking and I'm fine with this being a blocking call in my test.

Comment: How do you test message? await sutMethod.Should().ThrowAsync<Exception>().WithMessage("AlaMaKota"); ?

Answer (score 4):

Other variation of usage ThrowAsync method:

```
await Should.ThrowAsync<Exception>(async () => await Fail());
```

Answer (score 4):

With Fluent Assertions [v5.7](https://fluentassertions.com/releases/#570) they introduced the `Awaiting` overload so now you can do as following:

```
public async void TestFail()
{
    await this.Awaiting(_ => Fail()).Should().ThrowAsync<Exception>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Fluent Assertions v6.9 you can use short form:

```
var act = () => Fail();
act.Should().ThrowAsync<Exception>();
```